# OpenERP - many2one remove old data

Tags: field, odoo

I have a **one2many** which stores some data.

In **python**, when I need to update the object with **.write** method; the new data is stored but the old stuff remain there.

How can I empty the **many2many** before using **.write** method ??

Maybe using **.browse** and **.search** ?? please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great if you have posted some example of what you are trying to do. Any way, you have 2 solutions:

1. use `unlink()`
2. understand how the `write()` ORM method works on `one2many` fields.

Let take the example of `account.invoice` and `account.invoice.line`.

**The first approach - `unlink()`:**

```
def delete_lines(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    invoice_pool = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
    line_pool = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
    for invoice in invoice_pool.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        line_ids = [line.id for line in invoice.invoice_line]
        line_pool.unlink(cr, uid, line_ids, context=context)
```

**The second approach - `write()`**

Looking at the OpenERP docs (https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods/#osv.osv.osv.write):

```
write(cr, user, ids, vals, context=None)
...
Note: The type of field values to pass in vals for relationship fields is specific:

For a one2many field, a lits of tuples is expected. Here is the list of tuple that are accepted, with the corresponding semantics
(2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
```

So for the `vals` parameter we need a list of tuples in the following format:

```
[
    (2, line1_id),
    (2, line2_id),
    (2, line3_id),
    ...
]
```

The following code illustrates the use of the `write()` method.

```
def delete_lines(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    invoice_pool = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
    for invoice in invoice_pool.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        vals = [(2, line.id) for line in invoice.invoice_line]
        invoice.write(vals)
```

I didn't test the examples so let me know if they do the job.

Comment: Thanx for your answer; I posted how I solved it and it's pretty much your second option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

```
my_object = self.pool.get('my.main.object')
props = self.pool.get('table.related')
prop_id = props.search(cr, uid, [('id_1', '=', id_2)])
del_a = []
for p_id in prop_id:
   del_a.append([2, p_id])
my_object.write(cr, uid, line_id, {'many2one_field': del_a}, context=context)
```

Where: 
**del_a.append([2, p_id])** creates the string of tuples with code "2" (delete)
and **my_object** is where I need to make the changes.